# I need adobe flash player on my iOS app

Tags: ios, flash

I'm using UIWebView to load URL in my app, so while login into that URL, Home page of my application will come,
in that home page i have another button to call a new URL which needs Adobe Flash Player, so it is showing an error like
"This content requires Adobe Flash Player, which is not supported by your device. This content can be viewed on a desktop computer or on mobile devices that support Flash Player".
Could you please suggest me is there any third party library available to resolve this or i need to open that new URL in Safari Browser of iPad.

Comment: You need to make a mobile version of your home page that doesn't use Flash.

Comment: Means instead of using UIWebView may i have to code all the thing in Objective-c

Answer (score 2):

Apple famously [decided not to allow Flash on iOS devices for a number of reasons](https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) back in 2010. As far as I know, that hasn't changed. There are apparently [some apps that let you view Flash content](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2599798/apple-ios/how-to-run-flash-on-your-ipad-if-you-must.html), but it doesn't sound like a very good experience.

There's no Flash library that you can build into an app to access Flash. Since you control the web content in question, your best bet by far is to build a version of that content that uses HTML5 instead of Flash.

Even Adobe is [making the switch](http://www.cio.com/article/2376661/internet/how-adobe-is-moving-on-from-flash-to-embrace-html5.html) to HTML5; your Flash content has passed it's expiration date.